# sed: Invalid range end

Tags: linux, sed

I am using Lubuntu 19.04. I have a file called `text` which contains a mixture of upper case and lowercase characters. I am trying to replace all of these characters with `'*'`, but I'm being given an error message.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid range end
```

This is my code : `sed 's/[A-z]/*/g' text`

I was expecting an output of stars (*) to be shown on the screen, but instead I get this error message: `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid range end`

How do I fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. What version of sed are you using? Also, what happens when you try `sed 's/[A-Z]/*/g' text`?

Comment: @Beta How do I check the version of sed? ```sed 's/[A-Z]/*/g' text``` replaces all uppercase characters with *

Comment: Non-sed alternative fwiw: `tr 'A-Za-z' '[**]' < text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error since you have a invalide range  `[A-z]` with mix of upper/lower case

Correct range should be `[a-z]` all lower case, or `[A-Z]` all upper cas, or `[a-zA-Z]` mix, same as `[a-Z]`

So to replace all letter (upper and lower) with `*` you should use:

```
sed 's/[a-zA-Z]/*/g' text
sed 's/[A-Za-z]/*/g' text
sed 's/[a-Z]/*/g' text
```

Comment: `[A-z]` is not an invalid range, it contains all upper and lower characters and [, \, ], ^, _, `.

Comment: @oguzismail: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2: `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid range end`

Comment: @oguzismail Gnu sed 4.2.2 and 4.4 (ubuntu 18.04) definitely fails

Comment: Try `LC_ALL= sed 's/[A-z]/*/g'`, maybe it's related to locale?

Comment: @oguzismail still `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid range end`  So I do not see any reason for using `sed`with this range.

Comment: Yes. I was just saying `A-z` isn't invalid

Comment: @oguzismail from the gnu sed manual https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html it shows `‘[a-zA-Z0-9]’`, so I would never use some in a code that may fail on some system, so stay safe, keep away from `[A-z]`.  Or you could use `[:alpha:]`

Comment: @oguzismail All my system says `Invalid range end`, so I stick with `invalid` :)

Comment: It fails with 4.5, works with 4.6. I didn't see anything relevant in a quick skim of the changelog though. Might be a gnulib issue - I think sed uses that for its regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`[A-z]` is a valid range in the `C.UTF8` locale, however your machine is probably using `en_US.UTF8`, where the sorting (or *collation*) is more complicated (see the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) for more details).

The following should give the expected result on most distros: `echo aaa111 | LC_ALL=C.UTF8 sed 's/[A-z]/*/g'`